# Spring Boot does not correctly load profiles from application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-properties

I have a Spring Boot project and I'm injecting values to `application.yml` via the `application.properties` (this design makes sense for me since there are a lot of microservices and `application.properties` is actually a symlink) like this:

in `application.properties`:

```
PROPERTY_YAML=something
```

and then in `application.yml`:

```
app:
  property:
    yaml: ${PROPERTY_YAML}
```

This works just fine and when I'm accessing it via `Environment.getProperty` or via `@Value` everything works as expected. 
However, when I try to set the Spring Profile the same way, it does not work. Setting `SPR_PROFILE=my_profile` in `application.properties` and `application.yml` as

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${SPR_PROFILE}
```

results in the inconsistency in the spring when the `Environment.activeProfiles` returns `${SPR_PROFILE}` (and spring is running under this profile) and the property `Environment.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")` returns `my_profile`.

Is this expected behavior? Why is that? Does spring load profiles before actual parsing/replacing the placeholders?

My current workaround is to set `spring.profiles.active=my_profile` in `application.properties` but I was wondering, why is spring behaving that way.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot answer the specific question, but I wouldn't use both `application.properties` and `application.yml` as according to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) both are with the same priority and there's no guarantee which loads first:

> 12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar
>       (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
> 13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar
>       (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
> 14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar
>       (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 15. Application properties packaged inside your jar
>       (application.properties and YAML variants).

I would put all shared properties in a custom `*.properties` file - preferable with a profile (ex. `applicaion-dev.properties`) and activate that profile using one of Spring's [various ways](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles), which should guarantee loading before default properties.

Comment: The reason I have `application.properties` same for all microservices is that the same file is used as an `.env` file for docker-compose so it serves as multipurpose configuration file - it is convenient because it allows to startup the application locally on bare metal as well as in the docker environment with the same configuration and also allows you to have the config on the one place so we went with this "hack".

Therefore splitting it into profile dependent properties files does not solve anything.